# Is there any untyped but valid term in Gallina?

Tags: types, coq

I think every valid term of Gallina langauage has a associated type to it.
But is there any term, that is accepted by Coq, while doesn't being typed?

This is mostly about some translating things, but (I think) also a interesting thing to think about.

Comment: That would be a bug in the software.

Comment: @gallais I would be happy to conclude that, invalid terms are untyped terms, and untyped terms are all invalid. But to be precise, are there any exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Yves and gallais say, except for bugs in the system, every Gallina term accepted by Coq has a type.  This is almost by definition; to say that a term `t` is accepted by Coq is to say that `Check t` does not fail, and we can observe that `Check t` will always print a type of `t`.  Now, it may be the case that the type printed by `Check t` itself is ill-typed, but this, again, would be a bug in the system, and I have never seen it happen (as long as notations don't get in the way of reversibility of printing).

However, there are a couple of things that are close to what you are asking, that you might be interested in.

**Universes**

In Coq, we may write

```
Universe i.
Check Type@{i}.
```

However, although `i` is a valid universe, `Check i` fails, and `i` does not have a type in the sense that Gallina terms have types.

Note that in Agda, we may write

```
postulate foo : (i : Level) → Set i
```

and the Agda checker accepts that, but if we write

```
bar = (i : Level) → Set i
```

we get the error message `Setω is not a valid type`.  Coq does not have this issue, because universes are not terms in Coq, and universe polymorphism in Coq is prenex.

**Loss of subject reduction**

Coq has a few corner cases (possibly also called bugs) where subject reduction is lost.  That is, there are some well-typed terms that become ill-typed when you reduce them.  See, for example [bug #6768](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6768), which gives the code

```
CoInductive I := C : I -> I.
CoFixpoint infty := C infty.
Definition unfold : infty = C infty :=
  match infty as x return match x with C n => x = C n end with
  | C n => eq_refl (C n)
  end.
Fail Definition nf_unfold : infty = C infty := Eval lazy in unfold.
```

Note that we can get such an error even without type annotations, for example with

```
Axiom id : forall {T}, T -> T.
Definition nf_unfold := Eval lazy in id unfold.
(*Error: Illegal application:
The term "@id" of type "forall T : Type, T -> T"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "(cofix infty : I := C infty) = C (cofix infty : I := C infty)" : "Prop"
 "eq_refl"
   : "C (cofix infty : I := C infty) = C (cofix infty : I := C infty)"
The 2nd term has type
 "C (cofix infty : I := C infty) = C (cofix infty : I := C infty)"
which should be coercible to
 "(cofix infty : I := C infty) = C (cofix infty : I := C infty)".
*)
```

This is not exactly what you are asking about, but it seems related.

**Self-referential types**

All terms have types, but not all terms have the types that you want them to.  For example, given `A : Type` and `B : A -> Type`, you might want to write down the type of terms `f` which have type

```
forall b : bool, if b then A else B (f true)
```

Of course, this is not accepted by Coq, but we can define terms that have this type.  For example, given `A`, `B`, and `x : @sigT A B`, Coq accepts

```
Definition f := fun b : bool => if b return if b then _ else _
                                then projT1 x else projT2 x.
Check f : forall b : bool, if b then A else B (f true).
```

**Proofs of theorems which cannot be stated**

Back before Coq had explicit universe variables, I wanted to prove that function extensionality is downward closed.  That is, I wanted to prove the theorem

```
Set Universe Polymorphism.
Definition funext_at@{i} := forall (A B : Type@{i}) (f g : A -> B),
    (forall x, f x = g x) -> f = g.
Universes i j.
Constraint j <= i.
Theorem funext_downward_closed : funext_at@{i} -> funext_at@{j}.
```

However, there was no way to state this theorem.  I could only write

```
Theorem funext_downward_closed : funext -> funext.
```

I still managed to prove this theorem (see [this commit](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/commit/128a74742924838982b2c562769304bddfd0494c#diff-9c7372c5b2aa3f60ddeba4e71fbde579) and [this commit](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/commit/d92b27b390010f324ef7573b005eac64b07e9515#diff-9c7372c5b2aa3f60ddeba4e71fbde579) and [this issue](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/issues/334) in the [HoTT/HoTT](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT) library), though, by writing down the proof term, and checking the theorem afterwards to see whether or not the universe constraints were correct.  I jokingly said that I had proven an unspeakable theorem.

Answer (score 1):

No, every term of the calculus has to be well-typed.